# Use of if/else in an dictionary comprehension in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose that i have:

```
l = [
    ['Brasil', 'Italia', [10, 9]],
    ['Brasil', 'Espanha', [5, 7]], 
    ['Italia', 'Espanha', [7,8]],
    ]
```

and an empty dict:

```
d = {}
```

I'm trying to do this operation in an dict comprehension:

```
for x in l:
    if (x[0] not in d):
        d[x[0]] = 0
    else:
        d[x[0]] += 1

# Out: {'Brasil': 1, 'Italia': 0}
```

But when i try:

```
d = {k: (0 if (k not in d) else (d[k]+1)) for k in [x[0] for x in l]}

# Out: {'Brasil': 0, 'Italia': 0}
```

What an i doing wrong?

Comment: in your list is Brasil associated with 10 and Italia with 9 ?

Comment: This might be a job for [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: How would *d* look like for the given *l*?

Comment: @Feelsbadman only in an logical way

Comment: @CristiFati it would look like the first out." # Out: {'Brasil': 1, 'Italia': 0}"

Comment: The comprehension builds a new dictionary, then the assignment rebinds the name "d" to that dictionary. Your original dictionary stays empty.

Comment: @molbdnilo are u saing that during comprehensions D is empty during the comprehension and it only get the new dict when end?

Comment: Exactly. You have no access to your dict-in-progress within the comprehension while you're comprehending it.

Comment: Friends, i've understood my error, ty for fast help, i need to close or do something with post?

Comment: @Nefisto: It's already closed as a duplicate, but there is no harm in leaving it around. Just leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

Better way is using `Counter` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [
    ['Brasil', 'Italia', [10, 9]],
    ['Brasil', 'Espanha', [5, 7]], 
    ['Italia', 'Espanha', [7,8]],
    ]

c = Counter([x[0] for x in l])
c.subtract({x[0]: 1 for x in l})

print(c)
# Counter({'Brasil': 1, 'Italia': 0})
```

Comment: wrong output, counts are 1 higher

Comment: But i wanna to understand why it is not working, my comprehension look right for me, I need some clarify.  And the out is wrong

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Oops. Updated mine; not sure if it's too fancy. Thanks.

Comment: I din't think that is the right way to do, subtract is rlly ugly in this code

Comment: well it's not ideal iterating twice, but slightly better would be `c.subtract({k:1 for k in c})`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Easier: `c.subtract(c.keys())` (one of the few cases where calling `keys` is necessary on a `dict`, as it bypasses the path for subtracting mappings that `Counter.subtract` would otherwise use, which would reduce all counts to 0). Since it's a view though, no costly/large temporaries required. As for why the OP's code doesn't work, it's because until the `dict` comprehension is finished, the assignment to `d` doesn't happen (it constructs the new `dict` completely, then assigns), so there is no `d` (or only an old `d`) to look in. You can't reference the `dict` in progress.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for your insights here and on the other post, always interesting to read